# How to exchange client side (short living) access token to a long living one in LinkedIn Oauth v2 API?

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

After JS authentication there is a short lived (1800 seconds) access token available in the cookies (and in JS runtime).

Is it possible to exchange it to a long lived oAuth **v2** token?

PS: a special note: I know it's possible to exchange client-side v2 into server-side v1.0a. What I need is server-side v2.

Comment: Out of interest, what's the problem with using OAuth 1.0a on the server side?

Comment: @Arkanon: it's considered to be obsolete and is not recommended for use in new applications by LinkedIn itself.

Comment: @zerkms can you please share the reference? I still use their 1.0a version of Oauth. Was curious if it is getting deprecated.